# Differences between `phpinfo()` and `php -i` for same php.ini

Tags: php, apache, configuration, php-7

I have a lot of differences between what is shown on console via `php -i`, and what is shown by apache via `phpinfo()`.

For instance:

- pdo_mysql exists for the first case, not for the second one.
- `include` directive works only for the first case.

PHP.INI file is the same:

Console `php -i`:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1
>
> Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
>
> Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d
>
> Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
>
> PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, sqlite

VS Web `phpinfo()`:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lib
>
> Loaded Configuration File /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
>
> Scan this dir for additional .ini files   (none)
>
> Additional .ini files parsed  (none)
>
> PDO drivers   sqlite

---

For additional info, here is my apache configuration:

> LoadModule php7_module        /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
>
> PHPINIDir /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/
>
> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

And `include` directive in /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini

> include=/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/*.ini

I restarted apache after every php.ini modification.

---

Any idea, any clue?

Comment: because some servers use a `cli-php.ini` file for command line.  In other words you may have separate config files one for Apache one for the Command line.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix as you can see in the data given, it doesn't seem so. Loaded php.ini is the same.

Comment: But in the second your missing this additional one, `ext-xdebug.ini`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix you're right, that's one of the reasons why I created this thread...

Answer (score 1):

Solved, whereas php.ini was the same, there were 2 different PHP7 builds running on CLI and Apache. Tricky but solved!

Comment: Either by uninstalling all PHP instances and reinstalling just one, or by ensuring that your  PHP Apache module (`LoadModule php7_module [dir]/libphp7.so`) points to to the same PHP as your command line PHP (`which php`)

Comment: In my case I reinstalled everything with homebrew (OSX)

Comment: How did you found there were 2 different builds?

Comment: @EAmez `phpinfo()` from webpage and command line gave different build numbers.

Comment: "by ensuring that your PHP Apache module (LoadModule php7_module [dir]/libphp7.so) points to to the same PHP as your command line PHP" How do I check what the PHP Apache module points to?

Comment: @mario check the `LoadModule` directive, it's either in httpd.conf or something like `/etc/apache/modules/php7_module.conf`